# is there a way to customize the shadow in android

Tags: android, xml

I am trying to add shadow to my CardView in android
like this

```
   <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/testCard"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
        app:cardElevation="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cardView"
        android:translationZ="-5dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp">

        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

is there a way to customize the offset of the shadow so that the top shadow will be the same as the bottom

the things i try to do is this

[image]

this is how my work look
[image]

any help will be good thanks

Answer (score -1):

In cardView use

```
 app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
```

Answer (score -1):

**Try This:**
*Remove Cardview Use This Drawable backround in your Linear layout*

> Create: res-> drawable -> new -> Drawable Resource File -> cardback.xml

**cardback.xml**

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape>
        <padding android:top="0.5dp" android:right="0.5dp" android:bottom="1dp" android:left="0.5dp" />
        <solid android:color="#10CCCCCC" />
        <corners android:radius="8dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape>
        <padding android:top="0.5dp" android:right="0dp" android:bottom="1dp" android:left="0.5dp" />
        <solid android:color="#10CCCCCC" />
        <corners android:radius="7dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape>
        <padding android:top="1dp" android:right="1dp" android:bottom="1dp" android:left="1dp" />
        <solid android:color="#20CCCCCC" />
        <corners android:radius="6dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape>
        <padding android:top="0dp" android:right="0dp" android:bottom="1dp" android:left="0dp" />
        <solid android:color="#30CCCCCC" />
        <corners android:radius="5dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape>
        <padding android:top="0dp" android:right="0dp" android:bottom="1dp" android:left="0dp" />
        <solid android:color="#40CCCCCC" />
        <corners android:radius="4dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape>
        <padding android:top="0dp" android:right="0dp" android:bottom="1dp" android:left="0dp" />
        <solid android:color="#50CCCCCC" />
        <corners android:radius="3dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape>

        <padding android:top="0dp" android:right="0.1dp" android:bottom="0.5dp" android:left="0.1dp" />
        <solid android:color="#60CCCCCC" />
        <corners android:radius="3dp" />
    </shape>
</item>

<!-- Background -->
<item>
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
        <corners android:radius="3dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

**set backround in your Linear Layout:**

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@drawable/cardback">
</LinearLayout>
```